# Conditional dependencies for a Debian package

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies

I am creating a package that needs to depend on a package if another is installed, but needs a different dependency if no such package is installed. Is that possible using just the `control` file of the `.deb`, or are other tools needed? This package is actually meant for Ubuntu, so any tools unavailable in Ubuntu repositories can't be used.

Comment: The control file is static so no you can't change dependencies based on if a package is installed or not. What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe have a look at `Provides` or do something like `Depends: NotInstalled | Installed,`…

Comment: @UlrichDangel Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The control file is static so no you can't change dependencies on some external parameters but the [Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) specifies `|` as a way to specify alternative package names, in your case it would be something like:

```
Depends: Package1 | Package2
```

where `Package1` is the default dependency.